# Checking Actuator endpoints via function in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-functions, spring-boot-actuator

I'm writing Spring Boot apps and deploying them as Azure Functions.  I would love to be able to get the functionality from spring-actuator but with the Azure functions you invoke methods not endpoints.  So how could I get the out of the box /actuator/health functionality (without writing custom health checks) through methods?  I've only ever seen the Actuator data being accessed through the Rest Apis, but I am assuming there is someway to access the internal beans/methods to inject that logic into my functions.

**disclaimer, I am new to Azure so I might be completely missing a much easier solution**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out with your question - happy to help where I can.  Right now the Azure Functions java worker controls much of the HTTP routing so I suspect something like actuator won't work out of the box as we would need them to rely on our HTTP layer.  Interesting enough we have been working with the Spring team on integration already with things like [Spring Cloud Functions](https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/25/spring-cloud-function-2-0-and-azure-functions) so this is a good ask.

To get similar behavior though you can get health and metrics info directly from the Azure Functions telemetry streams out of the box (which we are always adding to). An overview of some of that functionality via Application Insights [can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring).  Let me know if that helps or if you have any other questions and great to hear you are giving Azure Functions a shot.

Comment: Thanks for the information, that is useful hooking up the functions to app insights.  If we come up with anything creative i'll update that back out here.